# How can I read a fstream into an LPSAFEARRAY?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, fstream, safearray

I'm trying to call a method on a managed dll in C++.  One of the parameters is a byte array, which the library import translated to LPSAFEARRAY.  The byte array/LPSAFEARRAY is intended to be the content of a file.  How can I read a file into a LPSAFEARRAY to pass into the method?

Here's the function signature from the generated library header file:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE AlterDocument(
   LPSAFEARRAY document/*[in]*/, 
   LPSAFEARRAY* pRetVal/*[out,retval]*/) = 0;
```

The second parameter is another byte array that I'll need to use when it comes back from the method.

Comment: I've added some tags like "safearray".

Comment: Good answers below.  Using CComSafeArray looks like the simplest, but I am having problems doing that with Borland C++.  I just don't know how, and can't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can initially create a `SAFEARRAYBOUND` and initialize it like a C array, e.g. `SAFEARRAYBOUND sabdBounds[2] = { {10, 0}, {20, 0\} };` and then use `SafeArrayCreate` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221234(v=vs.85).aspx) with the appropriate type and dimensions to get the needed `LPSAFEARRAY`.

**Update:**

Here is a piece of code that shows how to create the `LPSAFEARRAY`, as you can see i find the size of the file before creating the array so that i could be able to read data into it directly, you can also store the file contents in some intermediate buffer and then create the `SAFEARRAYBOUND` later:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::streampos fileSize = 0;
        std::ifstream inputFile("file.bin", std::ios::binary);
        fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
        inputFile.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
        fileSize = inputFile.tellg() - fileSize;
        SAFEARRAYBOUND arrayBounds[1] = { {fileSize, 0}}; // You have one dimension, with fileSize bytes
        LPSAFEARRAY safeArray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_I1, 1, arrayBounds);
        SafeArrayLock(safeArray);
        char* pData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(safeArray->pvData); // This should be the pointer to the first element in the array, fill in the data as needed
        // Do your stuff
        SafeArrayUnlock(safeArray);
        SafeArrayDestroy(safeArray);
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Any way you can be more specific?  Much of this is Greek to me.  Trying to find SafeArrayCreate examples are not much help.

Comment: You might want to add `SafeArrayLock`/`SafeArrayUnlock` for a cleaner code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ATL:

```
ifstream in(...);
CComSafeArray<BYTE> fileContents;

for (ifstream::traits_type::int_type ch = in.get(); ch != ifstream::traits_type::eof(); ch = in.get())
    fileContents.Add(ch);

managedObject->AlterDocument(fileContents, ...);
```

If you don't have ATL, you'll have to manipulate the SAFEARRAY directly without the CComSafeArray wrapper.

Comment: I'm not sure that calling `CComSafeArray::Add()` at each iteration is a good thing: `CComSafeArray` may have reallocation policies different from `std::vector` (which smartly uses geometric grow).

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to get the `ifstream` size, then create a `SAFEARRAY` with proper size to store the entire file content, and then `read()` the file content into the `SAFEARRAY` memory.

The code could be something like this (with the help of the convenient [`ATL::CComSafeArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) wrapper):

```
// Open the file
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("<<filename>>", ios::binary);
if (! inFile.is_open())
   // ... error

// Get length of file
inFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
const int length = inFile.tellg();
inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);


// Allocate SAFEARRAY of proper size.
// ATL::CComSafeArray<T> is a convenient C++ wrapper on raw SAFEARRAY structure.
CComSafeArray<BYTE> sa;
HRESULT hr = sa.Create(length);
if (FAILED(hr))
  // ... error

// Read data into the safe array
BYTE * dest = &(sa.GetAt(0));
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dest), length);

// Close the stream 
// (or let the destructor automatically close it when inFile goes out of scope...)
inFile.close();
```